# Accessing returned data from service in the controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working in a project that has AngularJS front-end and ASP.NET Web API back-end.

I have a service that calls the web API and returns a bunch of JSON data. I am trying to access that data in my controller, but I get an error saying the property I'm after is undefined! The property I'm after is the RegisteredKeeperName.

```
$scope.getCrateDetails = function (result, isInsert) {
    $scope.showCrateDetails = true;
    getCrateDetails();

    if (!$scope.premiumCrate.RegisteredKeeperName.toLowerCase().indexOf("Green Farm") > -1) {
        $scope.calloutClass = 'callout-danger';
        $scope.calloutMessage = 'We (Green Farm) cannot provide this service with the necessary documents.';
    } else {
        $scope.calloutMessage = 'All is good!';
    }
};
```

Even though when I print out the `$scope` I can see the property I'm after is populated with the correct information!

```
{{premiumCrate.RegisteredKeeperName}}
```

My service code like so:

```
function getCrateDetails() {
    // service call goes here.
    stockData.GetCrateDetails($scope.premiumCrate.Id).then(
        function (cData) {
            $scope.premiumCrate = cData;
        },
        function () {

        });
};
```

Comment: you must be having asynch issue with ajax. Please show your code that loads `RegisteredKeeperName`

Comment: too much code missing to get the whole picture...

Comment: Service code added. Let me know if you require any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCreateDetails` is an async call (you're trying to use the data before it has been returned and assigned), you should `return` that call using `.then` and access it in the controller, like so:

```
function getCrateDetails() {
    return stockData.GetCrateDetails($scope.premiumCrate.Id).then(function (cData) {
        return cData.data;
    }, function () {

    });
};
```

And make the call:

```
getCrateDetails().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //hey data!
    $scope.premiumCrate = data;

    if (!$scope.premiumCrate.RegisteredKeeperName.toLowerCase().indexOf("Green Farm") > -1) {
        $scope.calloutClass = 'callout-danger';
        $scope.calloutMessage = 'We (Green Farm) cannot provide this service with the necessary documents.';
    } else {
        $scope.calloutMessage = 'All is good!';
    }
});
```